# Why cadence's executions table with cassandra does not to split to multi tables

Tags: uber-api, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

Why cadence's executions table with cassandra does not to split to multi tables such as transfer_task and timer_task?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra doesn't support transactions across tables even if records share the same partition key. As Cadence provides transactional guarantees for workflow state updates and task creation they should be updated and inserted atomically. This forces us to put all of them into a single table. Note that SQL bindings don't have this problem and use separate tables.

See Samar's [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5M5eiNBUf4Q) for more details.